# how to redirect on same page area on button click without postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net, vb.net

On clicking button I want users to be redirected to some specific area in same page. I know it can be done with using anchor tags but not sure how will it possible with asp.button. On clicking button I want the user to redirect to a place holder. Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: you can also use a `#`

Comment: what -1 for ?  Whats wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<a href="#xxx">` tag, where `xxx` is an `<a name="xxx">` tag somewhere in your page.

Comment: Loadmaster how to trigger it on button click ? I have asp.button I dont want it to do a post back, want that button to redirect to this <a>. Please guide.

Comment: In these cases, I prefer to use the HTML `<input type='button' ...>` directly instead of an `<asp:Button ...>`. Note that you can still add `runat='server'` to the `<input>` element if you need to modify its attributes in the code-behind file.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, with out any check, just use javascript to add the anchor at the end of the link .

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"       
     OnClientClick="document.location.href+='#locA';return false;" />
```

and it will navigate to position of the : `<a name="locA"></a>`

and the correct way, that you can make many clicks with diferent anchors.

```
   <script>
        function cGoTo(where)
        {
            // take care if any other anhor exist to remove it.
            var url = document.location.href
            var tempArray = url.split("#");
            var baseURL = tempArray[0];

            document.location.href = baseURL + "#" + where;
        }
    </script>    
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="cGoTo('locA');return false;" />
```

And one online test: http://jsfiddle.net/r3Sav/