# One page website and ASP GridView postback issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a One page website with different sections. One particular section (2nd section) has a grid view which allows inline editing.

**Issue**: 
When the OnClick method is triggered, it causes a postback and the page scrolls to the first section.

To override this, i tried redirecting likewise:

```
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx#section2");
```

In this case, it perfectly redirects but the gridview edit template is lost and item template is again displayed. My guess is, the gridview is rebound.

I have tried the javascript way too from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512633/how-to-redirect-on-same-page-area-on-button-click-without-postback). It gives the same result.

```
<asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="Edit_OnClick" 
 OnClientClick="document.location.href+='#section2';return false;"></asp:Button>
```

I have also tried the portbackurl attribute of a link button. I get the same undesired result.

Any suggestions on how I should tackle this issue? I just want to be able to go to section 2 without a page refresh or redirect.
Thanks for you help in advance! :)

Comment: Thanks Yvette! Could you pls give me an example if possible? I am not able to find an example for JS Onchange event and grid view editing together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your gridview inside update panel like below and  update the update panel on code behind on button click

ASPX:

provide MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback to true on page tag

or you can make partial postback

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>

.......

  </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Edit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //code to update data or save data
            updList.Update();           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn about UseSubmitProperty or try this..

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="login.aspx#myModal">Forgot Password?</a>
```

and

```html
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.</p>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="emailForgot" placeholder="Email" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="btn btn-theme" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Submit</asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```